# RStudios Error > Error in Math.data.frame(souvenirs) : non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: Month

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to run the following function in RStudios:

```
autoplot(log(souvenirs))+ylab("Sales")
```

However, each time I run it I receive the following error.

```
Error in Math.data.frame(souvenirs) : 
  non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: Month
```

The dataset can be accessed by running the `fpp3` library and the using the `souvenirs` dataset. My assumption is that I may be receiving this error due to the "Month" column hacing both the year and the month within it.

I'm new to Rstudios and I tried to use the mutate function to split the "Month" column between year and month but no luck. I'm at a loos currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this dataset, the Month variable contains two information: Year and Month. Even before running autoplot function, if you try running summary(souvenirs), you will get errors. I could plot it using the following code:

```
df <- souvenirs %>% mutate(Year_Month = parse_date_time(Month,orders ="Y m")) %>% select(-Month)
df2 <- df[,1:2]
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(Year_Month = lubridate::ymd(Year_Month))
ggplot(df2,aes(x = Year_Month, y = log(Sales))) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you @eva, that work! I'll have to research the commands you used and how you used them as I'm not fully familiar with them. I will go line by line search what each expression means!